# Safari on ios v15.0 and web Worker

Tags: javascript, safari, service-worker, web-worker

I got a web worker work perfectly on all navigator except my favorite one. "Safari". The result is totaly random. Sometime it's work, sometime not, and i really not understand why.

My code is sample, but i probably do something wrong .. Any idea ?

Main.js

```
function CreateWorker(){
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     const w = new Worker("worker.js");
     w.onmessage = function (args) { alert("work fine");};
     w.onerror = function(e){ alert("error");};
     w.postMessage({ Size : 1280});
});

}
CreateWorker();
```

Worker.js

```
onmessage = function (args) {
postMessage({ Msg : "Received"});
}
```

So if i test it on multiple browser everyting work fine, but safari always give random result. Is it possible it's a cache story, or something i miss somewhere ?

Is it possible the worker is not finish to load the file, and are not ready to received the message ? If yes, is there a way to validate that the worker is ready to received a message ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I bet that, much like most other things that require an asset in order to work, `Worker` won't function as expected until its asset is loaded. However, I don't see a way to check for that, `Worker` doesn't have something like `onload`.

Comment: It's also my guess. I test with a setTimeout, it's seen working, but it's not enougth strong to use it in a production environement.

Comment: Maybe have the worker script be the first to send a message, indicating it's ready.

Comment: @CédricBoivin did you figure that one out? My workers work fine in any browser Windows, but won't run (or communicate?) in any browser iOS 16...